# Updating mysql table dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the table dynamically here

```
$QUERY = "UPDATE `internshala`.`student` SET `High_School` = \'$High_School\', `HS_Percentage` = \'$HS_Percentage\', `Intermediate` = \'$Intermediate\', `I_Percentage` = \'$I_Percentage\', `Graduation` = \'$Graduation\', `G_Score` = \'$G_Score\', `G_Year` = \'$G_Year\', `PG_Year` = \'$PG_Year\', `PostGraduation` = \'$PostGraduation\', `PG_Score` = \'$PG_Score\' WHERE `student`.`id` = '$_SESSION['user_id'];";
```

It throws the error `syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

I can't figure out the correct syntax for this, the above used syntax is something I deduced from phpmyadmin.

**PS: All the variables being used in the update statement are set to a not null value.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of issues with your query.  You are escaping single quotes while using double quotes to define your string.  You don't need this.

```
SET `High_School` = \'$High_School\',
```

should read

```
SET `High_School` = '$High_School',
```

Also, you are using a session variable at the end and not closing the quote

```
WHERE `student`.`id` = '$_SESSION['user_id'];";
```

You need to enclose the array item in curly braces and close the single quote:

```
WHERE `student`.`id` = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}';";
```

Your full query should look like this

```
$QUERY = "UPDATE `internshala`.`student` SET 
  `High_School` = '$High_School', 
  `HS_Percentage` = '$HS_Percentage', 
  `Intermediate` = '$Intermediate',
  `I_Percentage` = '$I_Percentage',
  `Graduation` = '$Graduation',
  `G_Score` = '$G_Score', 
  `G_Year` = '$G_Year', 
  `PG_Year` = '$PG_Year', 
  `PostGraduation` = '$PostGraduation', 
  `PG_Score` = '$PG_Score' 
 WHERE `student`.`id` = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}';";
```

Also don't use this method. You are open to sql injection.  You really should use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements.  Take a look at this post: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Now its You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Dr. VSEC\', `HS_Percentage` = \'12\', `Intermediate` = \'Dr. Vsec\', `I_Percen' at line 1s message

Comment: The values are being used from variables and yet this error?

Comment: I am passing each input through this function clean_input($data)
{
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = trim($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}


Is SQL Injection still possible?

Comment: Admittedly, your code does a good job of cleaing up the values. However, you're better off using the built in functions to minimize this possibility.  It's just good coding practice.